# Is it possible to have a Node.js websocket client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

So far I have only seen examples where an application in Node.js has been setup as a server for websockets. Usually the client is browser-based, and I have yet to see an example of a Node.js client.

How come there are so few examples on Node.js websocket clients? 
Alternatively, what other options are there for client-server communication?

Comment: @JeremyThille — Node.js *commonly* runs on servers. It is, however, a general purpose runtime.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There actually are many different examples.

I used the websockets package for example

https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

This code demonstrates a client in Node.js, not in the browser

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
        }
    });

    function sendNumber() {
        if (connection.connected) {
            var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
            connection.sendUTF(number.toString());
            setTimeout(sendNumber, 1000);
        }
    }
    sendNumber();
});

client.connect('ws://localhost:8080/', 'echo-protocol');
```

It's pretty easy, if you need further help, tell us!

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer!

Comment: sure no problem

Comment: Thanks for the example. Is there any example how keep connection up and handle that received data?

Comment: Please try to read this site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

[Current Features => Tunable Settings States:
-> Whether to automatically send ping frames for the purposes of keepalive
-> Keep-alive ping interval] 

Try to read the docu.

I did it manually for example, but that also had another reason.

And the data needs to be handled in connection.on('message'... part, because this is where data gets received.

Answer (score 6):

You can use W3C Websocket API for applications running on both Node and browsers (via the W3CWebSocket class).

https://websockets.spec.whatwg.org

```
npm install websocket
```

**Server Example**

Here's a short example showing a server that echos back anything sent to it, whether utf-8 or binary.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    // You should not use autoAcceptConnections for production
    // applications, as it defeats all standard cross-origin protection
    // facilities built into the protocol and the browser.  You should
    // *always* verify the connection's origin and decide whether or not
    // to accept it.
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
  return true;
}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
      // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
      request.reject();
      console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
      return;
    }
    
    var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log('Received Message: ' + message.utf8Data);
            connection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
        }
        else if (message.type === 'binary') {
            console.log('Received Binary Message of ' + message.binaryData.length + ' bytes');
            connection.sendBytes(message.binaryData);
        }
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    });
});
```

**Client Example**

This is a simple example client that will print out any utf-8 messages it receives on the console, and periodically sends a random number.

This code demonstrates a client in Node.js, not in the browser

```
var W3CWebSocket = require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;

var client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/', 'echo-protocol');

client.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Connection Error');
};

client.onopen = function() {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');

    function sendNumber() {
        if (client.readyState === client.OPEN) {
            var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
            client.send(number.toString());
            setTimeout(sendNumber, 1000);
        }
    }
    sendNumber();
};

client.onclose = function() {
    console.log('echo-protocol Client Closed');
};

client.onmessage = function(e) {
    if (typeof e.data === 'string') {
        console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

With Node.js 21 it's is possible as built-in:

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v21-release-announce

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/nodejs-21-is-here-features-that-will-blow-your-mind-fd996c8f0365