# Relay a websocket from a third party to Node JS server to react front end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

I'm trying to figure out how to relay [this Polygon websocket](https://polygon.io/docs/stocks/ws_stocks_a) from my Node JS server to my React front end. In other words, I want to establish a single websocket connection between Polygon and my server. I then want to relay that websocket so that any number of front end clients can establish a connection to that websocket from my server.

I'm able to connect my React front end to Polygon directly no problem, but only for internal testing since that doesn't scale (Polygon only accepts one websocket connection, don't want to expose Polygon API key to clients front end). Here is that code fwiw:

```
let socket;

useEffect(() => {
  if (marketStatus() !== 'closed') {
    socket = new WebSocket('wss://delayed.polygon.io/stocks');

  socket.onopen = () => {
    socket.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        action: 'auth',
        params: 'API_KEY',
      })
    );
  };

  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    // console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
    if (JSON.parse(event.data)[0].status === 'auth_success') {
      console.log(JSON.parse(event.data)[0].status);
      socket.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'subscribe', params: `A.${props.ticker}` }));
    }
    if (JSON.parse(event.data)[0].ev === 'A') {
      console.log(event.data)
    }
  };
  return () => {
    socket.close();
  };
  }
}, []);
```

I cannot find a simple example of the server code I need for the Node JS relay. Hoping there is one!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a Node.js websocket client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755518/is-it-possible-to-have-a-node-js-websocket-client)

Comment: No unfortunately. I need to also set up a Node.js websocket server to serve my front end

Comment: A quick Google gave this random untrusted package, but you could give it a go... https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-proxy-server